# Use of “same as” instead of “of”

Tags: meaning

Can ı use “ same as” in sentences instead “of” ?

> 1)I need 100 kg of the same soil as this sample you sent.
>   Instead of “of” in sentence;
>
> 2)need 100 kg of soil of this sample you sent.
>
> 3) I buy one same as your car.
>
> 4) I buy  one of your car.

Answer (score 2):

Your examples 1 and 2 are both possible but unlikely in practice.

Examples 3 and 4 are not grammatical.

If you have received a single sample from the supplier, you use either 1 or 2.

But it would clearer to say:

> I need 100 kg of the soil (supplied) in the/your sample.

If you have received more than one sample, you would need to specify:

> I need 100 kg of the soil (supplied) in your sample XYZ.

Regarding the cars, you need to rephrase your examples completely.

Either you mean:

> I wish to buy a car identical to yours.

or

> I wish to buy one of your cars.

Comment: I wish to buy a car identical to yours.or
I wish to buy one of your cars.Both has same meaning right?

Comment: @languagelearner No. "I wish to buy a car identical to yours" means I want a car which is very similar to your car, but not necessarily your car. "I wish to buy one of your cars" means I want to buy one of the cars that you own.